# This page isn’t working redirected you too many times error in magento

Tags: admin, magento-1.6

I am facing below error on site, This error only comes in admin end, In front-end site is working fine. After admin login, this error is coming please tell me how to debug this issue.

```
`This page isn’t working mysite.com redirected you too many times Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.
```

Comment: try clearing your cookies

Comment: Thanks, @Marius for your response. I found the solution, I changed web/url/redirect_to_base from 1 to 0 now admin end is loading.